# How to transfer old pokemon account to new phone

Tags: pokemon-go

I started playing pokemon on my old S5 but now have a shiny new S7, however I don't seem able to transfer the pokemon I have caught to the new phone. I can transfer the app but have to create a new account and begin again. I couldn't register as a trainer initially so had to sign up using Google account.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So just sign in with your google account ..

Comment: All your pokemon get saved to your account (which is on a server), not your phone.

Comment: there is no option to input a different account number so it just goes back to the start point

Comment: A comment has been put on about signing in as a different user but I don't see that option even after signing out and trying to go back in.